# How to take the amount from an input and add(+) to the amount table in db? (Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How to take the amount from an input and add(+) to the amount table in db? (Laravel)
I have this view :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osQsq.png)

and i have a table named Collaborators (which has an column named istoric_proiecte_sum_suma(made with withSum() function from laravel, in relationship with another table ProjectHistory that contains details about what collaborator works in any project and how much the owner paid him. and if the collab work on multiple projects the owners has to pay him multiple times, and if that, we have multiple inserts in ProjectHistory table with sums and withSum() function makes the relation between those and add the sum and display it to me) which contains the expenses, payments from the owner of the company to a collaborator) like you see in "suma" column in first image (suma = amount). So if i have a - amount the owner of the company needs to pay the collaborator and he pay him from completing that input and press "realizeaza plata" (translated -> make the payment).

So when he press "make payment" -> realizeaza plata, i need to add (+ sign operator) the amount that i typed in "suma" input to the "suma" (amount) column in first image(which is column istoric_proiecte_sum_suma).
My question is how do i resolve this problem because i have no idea. Look what i've tried:

CollaboratorController.php

```
public function realizeazaPlata(Request $request, Colaboratori $colaborator, $id)
    {
        $colaboratori1 = Colaboratori::findOrFail($id);
        $suma = $request->input('introduSuma');
        dd($suma);
        DB::update('UPDATE Colaboratori SET istoric_proiecte_sum_suma=? WHERE id=?', [($colaborator->istoric_proiecte_sum_suma + $suma), $colaboratori1->id]);
        return back();
    }
```

ColabsView.blade

```
<form action="{{ url('colaboratori') }}" method="POST">
@csrf
@method('GET')
<td>
<input type="text" name='introduSuma' placeholder="Suma">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Realizeaza plata</button>
</td>
</form>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('colaboratori', [App\Http\Controllers\ColaboratoriController::class, 'realizeazaPlata'])->name('realizeazaPlata');
```

Can someone help me please. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO ... why are you trying to spoof the `GET` method for the form? just set the form to use the `GET` method ... the 2nd and 3rd argument to your Controller action are unneeded as there are no route parameters for that route

Comment: why are unneeded because i store the input "amount" to $suma variable to add next to the istoric_proiecte_sum_suma.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you need to convert negative number to positive and then SUM it?

You could use abs() function:

```
$suma = abs($request->input('introduSuma'));
```

You should use type=number, to prevent users from entering characters:

```
<input type="number" name='introduSuma' placeholder="Suma">
```

Comment: no i don't want that. i just simple want to add the value from the input(where is the btn, after i press the btn) to the value from "suma" column

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like the following:

```
$colaboratori1 = Colaboratori::findOrFail($id); 
$suma = $request->input('introduSuma');

$colaboratori1->istoric_proiecte_sum_suma = $colaboratori1->istoric_proiecte_sum_suma + $suma;
$colaboratori1->save();
```

Comment: doesn't work. no error but not updating the sum when i type for example 300 in that input and press the btn, it is not doing anything. it shows me -1300 still